# php if id is exactly x

Tags: php, strpos

I'm using the following to check for a dynamic city id in urls that look like this:

```
 http://website.com/homes-for-sale-results/?cityId=10008&propertyType=SFR%2CCND&minListPrice=&ma
```

The php I'm using is this:

```
if (strpos($url, "cityId=9918"))  {
$cityName = "Allenhurst";} 
} elseif (strpos($url, "cityId=1000")) {
$cityName = "Highlands";
} elseif (strpos($url, "cityId=10009")) {
$cityName = "Holmdel";
```

This works except for when a cityid contains the id of another city because one has 4 digits and the other 5 digits. In the example above:  Highlands = "1000" and "Holmdel = "10009".

How do I query for the exact cityid?

Comment: You can filter by `strlen` of `cityId` first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right, `strpos` isn't a great solution for this.

You could break the problem down into a few smaller pieces first to make it easier.

Since it's a URL you could use [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/parse-url) first to extract the query string from the URL in a deterministic fashion. Then you'd be able to parse the individual pieces of that query string into individual data points using something like [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/parse-str). So from there you could just directly compare the numbers with a specific value.

```
$url = "http://website.com/homes-for-sale-results/?cityId=10008&propertyType=SFR%2CCND&minListPrice=&ma";

$query = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);

parse_str($query, $data);
$cityId = $data["cityId"];

if ($cityId == 9918) {
    $cityName = "Allenhurst";
} elseif ($cityId == 1000) {
    $cityName = "Highlands";
} elseif ($cityId == 10009) {
    $cityName = "Holmdel";
}
```

So in the first step `$query` gives us the exact query string from the URL (everything after the `?`). Then `$data` gives you each name/value pair, in the query string, as an array. Which means that finally, you can get the exact value of `cityId` from the query string through `$data["cityId"]` (which I just assign to `$cityId` here) and use that for direct comparison.